# Is it an offence if my landlord has no GFI's in the house and outside of the house?

Tags: gfci

I live in Gloucester Ottawa and there is no GFI's in our townhouses. I have general knowledge of electrical codes. Winter is approaching and I don't feel like getting electrocuted when I plug in my car or my Christmas lights. Also I don't think any units in my complex have GFI's.

Comment: I think we'll need to edit this to keep it within the site scope, but first: (1) what year was it built, (2) are there non-gfci outlets in the bath, kitchen, and outdoors, and (3) have you verified that you don't have gfci breakers?

Comment: City & County ordinance for rentals written for mandatory refit despite the age of the house is the only thing that will regulate that. You'll need to talk to your local planning office.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to check your local codes, but typically an installation is considered legal if it was up to code *when it was installed / built*. Doing major renovations may require you to bring the work up to code, but what exactly is required is up to your local inspectors.

If you're worried about getting shocked due to moisture you can use a [GFCI adapter](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=gfci%20adapter&rh=i%3aaps,k%3agfci%20adapter), which does exactly the same thing as the GFCI outlets: compare the hot current with the neutral current to look for any leakage (which typically is indicative of an undesirable condition).

(Note that there are still other ways you can get shocked... the GFCI just protects against a specific category of faults.)